# JQuery Tabs - change background colour of tab on input entry

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm creating a simple application which has 5 tabs and corresponding DIV's which contain some parts data and two input fields.  What I'm trying to achieve is when someone types a value in the .qty input, it changes the background colour of the currently selected tab - I've created a simple fiddle with the code I've currently got; it's dynamically created, but I've created the fiddle with static data.

To attempt to change the background I've done;

```
$('.qty').on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    $('.ui-tabs-active').addClass('tab-ok');
  }
})
```

But it doesn't do anything.  I'm not sure if I'm selecting the correct element, but from messing around with it, I did find a way of achieving it, but it broke the style in quite a bad manner.

What's the correct way to do this?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hyperjase/cL231env/17/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue of [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Your color override isn't working because it's not specific enough. You need to use something along the lines of:

```
#tabs .tab-ok {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: or...background: #ff0000 !important;

Comment: @gaetanoM I would not recommend using `!important`, it's a hack at best.

Comment: Thank you @Serg Chernata - can't quite believe it was something so amazingly simple ... spent hours playing with JQuery solely to try and get this done, totally overlooked the CSS aspect of it.